# How to edit method in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I want to make method edited in other part of code than creating method.

```
void End()
    {
    End();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
```

This method is already created and I want to edit it now without rewriting everything which is now in method.

I just want to know how to make something like

```
End() = End() + Console.WriteLine()
```

Comment: What's the desired output? And what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't. Don't try to mimic patterns from a different language. Explain the *problem* that you think this would be a solution for.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to `override` an existing `virtual` method:

In the *base* class:

```
// Note virtual keyword here
public virtual void End() 
{
   ...
}
```

In the *derived* class:

```
public override void End() 
{
   // We call existing End method from the base class
   base.End();

   // then we add requited extra logic
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)